# Cannot install serve to install react PWA

Tags: reactjs, serve, paw

I am really new to react and PWAs, so I am sorry if this is a simple fix but "npm install -g serve" is not working for me. Something about file permissio...? I am using MacOS btw....[screenshot of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5erG8.png)

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What version of React are you running? Share your package.json

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried installing using super user? Try this

```
sudo npm install -g serve
```